# select2 - adding tags with enter button

Tags: jquery-select2

I have a select field (multiple) and I need to add custom tags as well.
But when I enter a custom data and click on enter, it does not work. When the ajax request finished,  my custom data appears in drop down, only after that I can select it from drop down. Is it possible to add tags after clicking on enter button?

```
<select id="autocomplete" multiple="multiple" name="to[]"></select>

$("#autocomplete").select2({
        ajax: {
          url: url,
          dataType: 'json', 
          cache: false
        },  
        tags: true,           
        minimumInputLength: 1 
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to set *selectOnClose* to true (default is false)?

> selectOnClose *boolean*   **false**   Implements automatic selection when the dropdown is closed.

See https://select2.org/configuration/options-api for further details. Last but not least: A jsfiddle would be very helpful for others to play around with your issue.

*Update*: In my case I stumbled upon the Results.highlightFirstItem function - so setting `selectOnClose` to true was not necessary:

```
Results.prototype.highlightFirstItem = function () {
    var $options = this.$results
      .find('.select2-results__option[aria-selected]');

    var $selected = $options.filter('[aria-selected=true]');

    // Check if there are any selected options
    if ($selected.length > 0) {
      // If there are selected options, highlight the first
      $selected.first().trigger('mouseenter');
    } else {
      // If there are no selected options, highlight the first option
      // in the dropdown
      $options.first().trigger('mouseenter');
    }

    this.ensureHighlightVisible();
};
```

changed to:

```
Results.prototype.highlightFirstItem = function () {
    var $options = this.$results
      .find('.select2-results__option[aria-selected]');

    // Highlight the first option
    $options.first().trigger('mouseenter');

    this.ensureHighlightVisible();
};
```

Please note that this is a quick'n'dirty solution and a proper request (aka new issue in github) needs to be created (if that is your issue at all as well).